# How to test that a function is wrapped with a decorator (javascript)

Tags: javascript, sinon, chai, ecmascript-next

I've written and used a decorator in my project, and I'm now trying to test that the functions that are wrapped with the decorator *are* wrapped with the decorator.

I guess I could test that what is happening within the decorator is happening, which I already know how to do, but my preference would be to mock out the decorator entirely and just assert that the function is being wrapped with it.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this (hopefully with sinon/chai)?

Comment: Check for the functionalities the decorator should have shared with the decorated function/class

Comment: Offtop. Decorators is not feature of ES7. Stage 2 yet. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

Comment: I don't want to check that the decorator is doing something, I'm trying to unit test it. And @Artin you are correct, but my question still stands, how should I edit the question to reflect that?

Comment: @BenHare Simply don't say ES7 in your title or body since it is not ES7 (rather ES2016). It may be part of ES2017 but it's still at Stage 2.

Comment: @Artin What's on-topic then? There's no such thing as 'ES7' at all, the real name of the spec is ES2016. While ES7 is obsolete term for ES.next and *always* used in this context on SO.

Comment: @estus, hover on 'ecmascript-7' tag below the question. It says it's equivalent of ecmascript 2016 and not ES.next on SO

Comment: This isn't offtopic. It's just tagged incorrectly. @Artin, just edit the question with the appropriate tag (if there is one), or just remove the offending tag. No need to cause ruckus.

Comment: @BenHare You can't do anything like that. Decorators are just ordinary functions in transpiled code. You can use a generic way to mock CJS modules with Babel and Rewire/Proxyquire and thus mock/stub imported decorator functions. Please, update the question with relevant details on your building and testing configurations.

Comment: have you guys tried ES9 maybe it'll work for everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no metadata about objects that they were decorated by any specific function - decorators are just syntactic sugar and could be applied in a different way as well.

So yes, asserting that what should happen in the decorator actually did happen is the only way. You *can* mock the decorator and test explicitly that it was applied by setting a specific flag or even checking the arguments and return value of the decorator, but you probably should not. Decorators are an implementation detail, don't test for them - test for the behaviours that the decorator provides.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, figured I'd ask if it was possible before falling back on the other way.